# Find coefficient of x in a generating function

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

The problem is as follows:

$\text{Determine the coef. of } x^{10} \text{ in } (x^3 + x^5 + x^6)(x^4 + x^5 + x^7)(1+x^5+x^{10}+x^{15}+...)$

I factored out some $x$'s, to get 
$x^3(1+x^2+x^3)x^4(1+x+x^3)(1+x^5+x^{10}+x^{15}+...)$
and then combined the factored terms to get 
 $x^7(1+x^2+x^4)(1+x+x^3)(1+x^5+x^{10}+x^{15}+...)$

Now I don't know what to do; usually it ends up factoring to $(1+x+x^2+...)$, but that doesn't appear to be the case here.

Comment: 10=7+3 ,10=7+2+1

Comment: Or from the unfactored form 10=3+7+0 and 10=5+5+0.

Comment: @Drew So, you can only add exponents that are within their parentheses? The 3 and the 7 are in the same bracket.

Comment: @Nxt3 actually the opposite. Think about how you would expand the product. You take one term from the first bracket, one from the second, and one from the third and multiply them together -- and then you add every such possible combination. So the coefficient of $x^{10}$ is the number of ways of taking one term from each bracket such that their exponents add to 10.

Comment: For such problems, I also encourage you to use [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x%5E3%2Bx%5E5%2Bx%5E7%29*%28x%5E4%2Bx%5E5%2Bx%5E7%29+%2F+%281-x%5E5%29)

Comment: @Drew So, I had typed up the wrong problem. Some of the coef. changed. Having said that, does it matter if you pick the terms before or after factoring? Do I even need to factor?

Comment: You don't need to factor (the result doesn't change), though in some cases factoring might help you count.

Comment: @Drew After I figure out which values to multiply to get $x^{10}$, what do I do then? This is where I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiplying the first two factors you find:
$x^7+ x^8+x^9+2x^{10} + $  other monomials of degree $n>10$ and, when you multiply such polynomial with the third factor, you see that the only monomial in $x^{10}$ has coefficient $2$ since all other terms have exponents $n=7,8,9$ or $n>10$.

---

**Hint:**

The OP has changed: so for this version the answer is:

Multiplying the first two factors you find:
$x^7+ x^8+x^9+3x^{10} + $  other monomials of degree $n>10$ and, when you multiply such polynomial with the third factor, you see that the only monomial in $x^{10}$ has coefficient $3$ since all other terms have exponents $n=7,8,9$ or $n>10$.

Comment: note : coefficient of  $$x^{10}$$ is 3

Comment: Why? I see only the terms $x^3x^7$ and $x^5x^5$.

Comment: Does it even matter if I factor first? I can get the same number of cases either way.

Comment: @Ntx3 Ther is not a product $x^6x^4$. look at the edit in my answer.

Comment: @Ntx3 OK, now your question is correct, and you can see that my answer is correct.(and you can upvote if you like)

Comment: @EmilioNovati Yeah, I wrote this problem down twice--one correctly, and one incorrectly. I made sure the OP was correct.

However, when/how do combinations come into your answer? I know that at some point, I'm supposed to put stuff into combinations to calculate the coef.

Comment: @EmilioNovati I've updated the OP with the correct problem. Forgive me.

Comment: I want to upvote all of the answers, but I lack rep. :\

Answer (score 2):

From the sum $\frac{1}{1-x^5}$ you only need to consider the first two terms - other will give you a higher power. $10 = x_1 +x_2+ x_3$ (with terms all three sums). Can you idenify $x_k$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint :**
coefficient of $x^3$ in $(1+x^2+x^3)(1+x+x^4)(1+x^5+x^{10}+x^{15}+...)$ is $2$, because
$x^3=x^3\times 1 \times 1, x^3= x^2\times x \times 1$

Comment: look! there is a mistake in the factorization of OP: $x^3+x^5+x^7=x^3(1+x^2+x^4)$ not $x^3(1+x^2+x^3)$

Comment: @Emilio_Novati Oops. My bad.